# How to use Dagger2 library

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

In my application i want use **`Dagger2`** and for this i write below codes.
My component class name is **MainComponent** but after **rebuild** project when i want use this, not found me **DaggerMainComponent**!
I **rebuild** the project several times, but it did not work again!

**My Dagger dependency:**

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'
```

**My Module class:**

```
@Module
public class ApiServiceModule {
    private Context context;

    public ApiServiceModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    public ApisList getApisList(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(ApisList.class);
    }

    @Provides
    public Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**My Component class :**

```
@Component(modules = ApiServiceModule.class)
public interface MainComponent {
    ApisList getApisList();
}
```

**My mainActivity class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

How can i fix it? please help me

Comment: Wow..Jake contributes to Dagger2 library and now asking question on his own contribution? God is crazy

Comment: @PareshMayani, i'm another jake warton :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you dependency codes to this :

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
```

First add this dependencies then click on **Make project** (**ctrl+f9** shortcuts) .
After finish rebuild project you can access to **DaggerMainComponent** .

I hope help you

Comment: Thanks dear friend. i changed this and fix it. thanks